# HTML & JavaScript - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a home page with the Bootstrap CMS. I currently have everything working apart from when the user comes onto the website I want a [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) to appear as soon as they go onto the website.

The current code I have for the Modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now, this is all fine,

The JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
</script>
```

As you should know with them together should make the Modal appear automaticlly but it's not.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included on your page?

Comment: Do you have FireBug (for Firefox) or the Chrome console up? Check to see if you're getting any Javascript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You have 2 choices here.***

**1. When the page is loaded**

```
function init() {
    $('modal_selector').modal();
}

window.onload = init;
```

**2. When the document is ready.**

```
function handleReady() {
    $('modal_selector').modal();
}

$(document).ready(handleReady);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use $(window).load(...), instead you need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

And be sure you have load jQuery api in your index.html.

I hope this will help you!